# Can i use survival analysis to predict if a person will "die" or not, and then get the survival time if the person does?

Tags: classification, regression, predictive-modeling, survival-analysis

I want to determine, given a project, "How long will it take for this project to be successful ?"

Therefore, survival analysis seems like a perfect fit in this case (as I do have some projects that ended up as censored data as they took too long to be successful).

However, I also want to build my model so that, if a project seems like it will take too long (for instance it will be more than 2 months - the duration of the study) it will tell me not to accept it.

To sum it up ideal model for me would be :

- Input : a project (with features like Founding, Past success, Location, etc.)
- The models tells me if I should accept the project or not
- If I should accept it, how long will it take before being successful ?

Is it doable with only survival analysis or should I consider adding a classification algorithm before that ?

Comment: The answer may depend on what decisions you are making with the model. If it's i)  always a simple yes/no action, and ii) you _apriori_ know the threshold (you allude to 2 months), then classification makes sense. If either of these isn't true, then survival analysis would make more sense.

Comment: Also, if you choose to go classification, and your threshold is N months, then I think using any "starts" from the past N months would cause bias (as you'll only see successes in the past N months - know what I mean). This will limit the amount / recency of your dataset